# Analytical result for element-wise vector division?

Tags: matrices

I have two vectors

$$a=[a_1,a_2,...,a_n], b=[b_1,b_2,...,b_n]$$

Is it possible to express the result $$c=[a_1/b_1,a_2/b_2,...,a_n/b_n]$$ by some standard matrix operations such as matrix multiplication and inverse?

Comment: Do you consider the map $\text{diag}: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^{n \times n}$ to be elementary, where $\text{diag}$ maps a vector ${\bf b} := [b_1, \ldots, b_n]^T$ to the matrix with $(i, j)$ entry $b_i$ if $i = j$ and $0$ otherwise? If so, we can write ${\bf c} = \text{diag}({\bf b})^{-1} {\bf a}$.

Comment: I'm afraid not. The problem I'm facing is that the a and b are the product of some matrices and I want to know if I can simplify it. $a=C\times A$, $b=C\times B\times A$, where $A,B\in R^{n\times n},C\in R^{1\times n}$

Comment: Vector-matrix multiplication?  But elementwise division is of no help for that.

Answer (score 0):

$$D = \text{diag(b)}=
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}  b_1\\ b_2\\ \vdots \\ b_n \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}  1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \end{bmatrix}
+\\
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}  b_1\\ b_2\\ \vdots \\ b_n \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}  0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \end{bmatrix}\\
+\\
\vdots\\
+\\
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}  b_1\\ b_2\\ \vdots \\ b_n \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}  0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$\text{c=D}^{-1} {\bf a}$$
Calculation of $\text{D}^{-1}$ is easy as it is just $1/b$'s.